# Controlling an LED strip with a presure sensor and pulse using an Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino

I have two separate [sketches](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) and the pressure sensor and the pulse sensor are working fine. Alone, these are fine, but when I try to combine both they stop working on me. How can I fix this problem?

```
//Code for pressure sensor
int fsrAnalogPin = 0; // FSR is connected to analog 0
int LEDpin0 = 11;     // Connect red LED to pin 11 (PWM pin)
int LEDpin1 = 10;
int LEDpin2 = 9;
int fsrReading;       // The analog reading from the FSR resistor divider.
int LEDbrightness;

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(9600); // We'll send debugging information via the Serial monitor.
    pinMode(LEDpin0, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LEDpin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LEDpin2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(void) {
    fsrReading = analogRead(fsrAnalogPin);
    Serial.print("Analog reading = ");
    Serial.println(fsrReading);

    // We'll need to change the range from the analog reading (0-1023) down to the range
    // used by analogWrite (0-255) with map!
    LEDbrightness = map(fsrReading, 0, 1023, 1, 255);
    // LED gets brighter the harder you press.
    analogWrite(LEDpin0, LEDbrightness);
    analogWrite(LEDpin1, LEDbrightness);
    analogWrite(LEDpin2, LEDbrightness);

    delay(100);
}

//Code for pulse sensor comes in two tabs this is the first tab.
int analogPinR = 11;
int analogPinG = 10;
int analogPinB = 9;

//The buffer
int RGB[9];

//Values of red, green and blue.
int R=0;
int G=0;
int B=0;
int pulsePin = 1;                // Pulse Sensor purple wire connected to analog pin 0.
int fadeRate = 0;                // Used to fade LED on with PWM on fadePin.
//int fadePin = 9;               // Pin to do fancy classy fading blink at each beat.
//int fadePin1 = 10;             // Pin to do fancy classy fading blink at each beat.
//int fadePin2 = 11;             // Pin to do fancy classy fading blink at each beat.

// These variables are volatile, because they are used during the interrupt service routine!
volatile int BPM;                // Used to hold the pulse rate..
volatile int Signal;             // Holds the incoming raw data.
volatile int IBI = 600;          // Holds the time between beats, the Inter-Beat Interval.
volatile boolean Pulse = false;  // True when pulse wave is high, false when it's low.
volatile boolean QS = false;     // Becomes true when Arduino finds a beat.

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);          // We agree to talk fast!
    interruptSetup();            // Sets up to read the pulse sensor signal every 2 ms.
}

void loop(){
    sendDataToProcessing('S', Signal);  // Send Processing the raw pulse sensor data.
    if (QS == true){                    // Quantified Self flag is true when Arduino finds a heartbeat
        fadeRate = 255;                 // Set 'fadeRate' variable to 255 to fade the LED with a pulse.
        sendDataToProcessing('B',BPM);  // Send heart rate with a 'B' prefix.
        sendDataToProcessing('Q',IBI);  // Send time between beats with a 'Q' prefix.
        QS = false;                     // Reset the Quantified Self flag for next time.
    }
    delay(20);                          // Take a break

    if (BPM > 120) {
        pinMode(analogPinR,255);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,0);       // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,0);       // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
    }
    else if (BPM > 90){ //Yellow
        pinMode(analogPinR,255);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,80);      // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,5);       // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
    }
    else if (BPM > 85){//turk
        pinMode(analogPinR,0);       // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,204);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,102);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
    }
    else if (BPM > 80){//green/blue
        pinMode(analogPinR,0);       // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,255);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,255);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
    }
    else if (BPM > 75){//blue/green
        pinMode(analogPinR,0);       // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,128);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,255);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
    }
    else if (BPM > 70){//blue/purple
        pinMode(analogPinR,102);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,102);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,255);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
    }
    else if (BPM > 65){//purple
        pinMode(analogPinR,178);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,102);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,255);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
    }
    else if (BPM > 60){//blue
        pinMode(analogPinR,0);       // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,0);       // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,255);     // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
    }

    //AURORA
    else {
        //Blue
        pinMode(analogPinR,0);    // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,0);    // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,255);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        delay(300);

        //Green
        pinMode(analogPinR,0);    // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,255);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,0);    // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        delay(300);

        //Orange
        pinMode(analogPinR,255);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,128);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,0);    // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        delay(300);

        //Yellow
        pinMode(analogPinR,255);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,255);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,0);    // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        delay(300);

        //Light blue
        pinMode(analogPinR,0);    // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,255);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,255);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        delay(300);

        //Purple
        pinMode(analogPinR,255);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinG,0);    // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        pinMode(analogPinB,255);  // Pin that will blink to your heartbeat!
        delay(300);
    }
}

void ledFadeToBeat(){
    fadeRate -= 15;                        // Set LED fade value
    fadeRate = constrain(fadeRate,0,255);  // Keep LED fade value from going into negative numbers!
    // analogWrite(fadePin2,fadeRate);     // Fade LED
}

void sendDataToProcessing(char symbol, int data ){
    Serial.print(symbol);                  // Symbol prefix tells Processing what type of data is coming
    Serial.println(data);                  // The data to send culminating in a carriage return
    Serial.println(BPM);                   // Print to the laptop screen
    ledFadeToBeat();

    if(Serial.available()==9){
        for(int i =0;i<9;i++){
            RGB = Serial.read() - '0';
        }

        //Get the data from the integer array
        R = RGB[0]*100+RGB[1]*10+RGB[2];
        G = RGB[3]*100+RGB[4]*10+RGB[5];
        B = RGB[6]*100+RGB[7]*10+RGB[8];
    }
}

//This is the second tab
volatile int rate[10];                     // Used to hold last ten IBI values
volatile unsigned long sampleCounter = 0;  // Used to determine pulse timing
volatile unsigned long lastBeatTime = 0;   // Used to find the inter beat interval
volatile int P =512;                       // Used to find peak in pulse wave
volatile int T = 512;                      // Used to find trough in pulse wave
volatile int thresh = 512;                 // Used to find instant moment of heart beat
volatile int amp = 100;                    // Used to hold amplitude of pulse waveform
volatile boolean firstBeat = true;         // Used to seed rate array so we startup with reasonable BPM
volatile boolean secondBeat = true;        // Used to seed rate array so we startup with reasonable BPM

void interruptSetup(){
    // Initializes Timer2 to throw an interrupt every 2mS.
    TCCR2A = 0x02;  // Disable PWM on digital pins 3 and 11, and go into CTC mode.
    TCCR2B = 0x06;  // Don't force compare, 256 prescaler.
    OCR2A = 0X7C;   // Set the top of the count to 124 for 500 Hz sample rate.
    TIMSK2 = 0x02;  // Enable interrupt on match between TIMER2 and OCR2A.
    sei();          // Make sure global interrupts are enabled.
}

// This is the timer 2 interrupt service routine.
// Timer 2 makes sure that we take a reading
// every 2 miliseconds.
ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect){                         // Triggered when Timer2 counts to 124
    cli();                                      // Disable interrupts while we do this
    Signal = analogRead(pulsePin);              // Read the pulse sensor
    sampleCounter += 2;                         // Keep track of the time in ms with this variable.
    int N = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;       // Monitor the time since the last beat to avoid noise.

    // Find the peak and trough of the pulse wave
    if (Signal < thresh && N > (IBI/5)*3){      // Avoid dichrotic noise by waiting 3/5 of last IBI.
        if (Signal < T){                        // T is the trough.
            T = Signal;                         // Keep track of lowest point in pulse wave.
        }
    }

    if (Signal > thresh && Signal > P) {        // A threshold condition helps avoid noise.
        P = Signal;                             // P is the peak.
    }                                           // Keep track of highest point in pulse wave.

    // Now it's time to look for the heart beat
    // signal surges up in value every time there is a pulse
    if (N > 250){                               // Avoid high frequency noise
        if ( (Signal > thresh) &&
             (Pulse == false) &&
             (N > (IBI/5)*3) ){

            Pulse = true;                        // Set the pulse flag when we think there is a pulse.
            digitalWrite(analogPinR,HIGH);       // Turn on bluepin LED.
            digitalWrite(analogPinG,HIGH);       // Turn on redpin LED.
            digitalWrite(analogPinB,HIGH);       // Turn on greenpin LED.

            IBI = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;  // Measure time between beats in ms.
            lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;        // Keep track of time for next pulse.

            if (firstBeat){                      // If it's the first time we found a beat, if firstBeat == TRUE
                firstBeat = false;               // Clear firstBeat flag.
                return;                          // IBI value is unreliable so discard it.
            }
            if (secondBeat){                     // If this is the second beat, if secondBeat == TRUE.
                secondBeat = false;              // Clear secondBeat flag.
                for(int i=0; i<=9; i++){          // Seed the running total to get a realisitic BPM at startup.
                    rate = IBI;
                }
            }

            // Keep a running total of the last 10 IBI values.
            word runningTotal = 0;       // Clear the runningTotal variable

            for(int i=0; i<=8; i++){     // Shift data in the rate array
                rate = rate[i+1];      // And drop the oldest IBI value
                runningTotal += rate;  // Add up the 9 oldest IBI values
            }

            rate[9] = IBI;               // Add the latest IBI to the rate array
            runningTotal += rate[9];     // Add the latest IBI to runningTotal
            runningTotal /= 10;          // Average the last 10 IBI values
            BPM = 60000/runningTotal;    // How many beats can fit into a minute? that's BPM!
            QS = true;                   // Set Quantified Self flag
            // QS flag is not cleared inside this interupt service routine (ISR)
        }
    }

    if (Signal < thresh && Pulse == true){  // When the values are going down, the beat is over.
        // digitalWrite(analogPinR,LOW);    // Turn off red LED.
        // digitalWrite(analogPinG,LOW);    // Turn off green LED.
        // digitalWrite(analogPinB,LOW);    // Turn off blue LED.
        Pulse = false;                      // Reset the pulse flag, so we can do it again.
        amp = P - T;                        // Get amplitude of the pulse wave.
        thresh = amp/2 + T;                 // Set thresh at 50% of the amplitude.
        P = thresh;                         // Reset these for next time.
        T = thresh;
    }

    if (N > 2500){                     // If 2.5 seconds go by without a beat
        thresh = 512;                  // Set thresh default
        P = 512;                       // Set P default
        T = 512;                       // Set T default
        lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;  // Bring the lastBeatTime up to date
        firstBeat = true;              // Set these to avoid noise
        secondBeat = true;             // When we get the heartbeat back
    }
    sei();                             // Enable interrupts when youre done!
}// end ISR
```

Comment: The code you're posting is you're actually Arduino sketch? I mean, do you have a sketch with two setup functions and two loop functions?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828).

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, I don't know your experience (and I don't want to make you mad).

**If you are new to programming**

Sr. Richie asks if this was one file? In an Arduino [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) (and most computer languages) each function must have its own name. Furthermore, Arduino has special functions named **setup()** and **loop()**.

**If you have been around the block**

```
ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect){               // Triggered when Timer2 counts to 124
```

This could really mess with your control flow. Regardless of where/what you are doing, you will stop and do this ISR request. Maybe you're in the middle of doing the following when you jump away and do the ISR.

```
 RGB = Serial.read() - '0';
```

This could mess up your serial communication (or anything time-dependent).

I assume it was you in the forum post 

*[Arduino UNO - Controling LED strip with presure sensor & pulse sensor](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=169102.0)* .

Comment: Let us know more about the issue and we can give more help

Comment: Actually, an ISR won't harm serial *transmit* at all - it might delay the next character slightly but that would only be a problem if so much data was being sent that unsent data that small delays means that the speed of producing the data starts to exceed that of transmitting it.  For serial *receive* it could be an issue, but that is not being used here.

Comment: You are spot-on Mr. Stratton. Sorry, I was looking for something that could trip some one up. I will statment above using the line  RGB=Serial.read() - '0';

Answer (score 1):

The second set of code contains errors.

pinMode() is not the way to set analog outputs.  All these are not correct:

```
//orange
pinMode(analogPinR,255);
pinMode(analogPinG,128);
pinMode(analogPinB,0);
```

And you have not configured the pins as output.

What you need is to configure **once** in setup:

```
pinMode(ledG, OUTPUT);
```

and write in the loop:

```
analogWrite(ledG, 128);
```

Fix that and at least the LED's should function as you expect.